# Turn off privacy popup in VS Code

Tags: popup, visual-studio-code, privacy

How do I turn off the privacy popup? It's driving me nuts - it popups every single time I start a new instance of VS Code!!

[image: Privacy popup]

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

Configure these options on user settings (`ctrl+,`):

```
"telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
"telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false
```

Then reload your vscode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this did not work. I've set them both to false, and both to true and I still get the popup. Perhaps just reinstall vscode?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version.